# MongoEngine remove string from ListField

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

code:

```
class Users(db.Document, UserMixin):
    first_name = db.StringField()
    last_name = db.StringField()
    username = db.StringField(unique=True)
    password = db.StringField()
    email = db.StringField()
    following = db.ListField(db.StringField(), default=[])
    role = db.ListField(db.StringField(), default=["user"])
    confirmed = db.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed_on = db.DateTimeField()
```

so if I wanted to remove a certain string from the `Users.following` field

`Users.objects(username="some_user").update(pull__following=["some_string"])`
and then save it?

because I've tried this and it won't remove the string from the `following` `listField`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove one element from your list you need to use the `pull` modifier which takes a single value not a list as you are doing so the correct query is:

```
Users.objects(username='some_user').update(pull__following='some_string')
```

You can also remove several element from your "following" list using the `pull_all` modifier; and in this case you pass in a list of value.

```
Users.objects(username='some_user').update(pull_all__following=['one_string', 'another_string'])
```

Comment: so that's why. `pull` will take only a single value while `pull_al`l takes a `list` or `tuple`